# How can I make my program run faster

Tags: c#, excel, algorithm, duplicates

I have made a program in c# that reads and removes duplicate. It works fine with 0-5000 values but when I tried it with 100,000 values it takes too long or NOT-RESPONDING. Any suggestions on how to fix it? Below is my algorithm.

```
try
{
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt); //read excel file  

dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcel;

mydatagrid.Rows.Clear();
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string exists = "no";

    //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    if (mydatagrid.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        mydatagrid.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        int b = 1;
        while (b < (mydatagrid.Rows.Count - 1))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(mydatagrid.Rows[b].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == mydatagrid.Rows[b].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                exists = "yes";
            }
            else
            {

            }
            b++;
        }

        if (exists == "no")
        {
            mydatagrid.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bools are faster than strings (`exists`), and also the *correct* type to use.  You should stop looping when you have the information you need (`break`).  If you can find a way to move your special condition for a count of 1 OUTSIDE the loop (and I think you can), you should do so.

```
  try
  {
    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt); //read excel file  

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcel;

    mydatagrid.Rows.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      bool exists = false;


      if (mydatagrid.Rows.Count == 1)
      {
        mydatagrid.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
      }
      else
      {
        for (int b = 1; b < (mydatagrid.Rows.Count - 1); b++)
        {
          //MessageBox.Show(mydatagrid.Rows[b].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
          if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == mydatagrid.Rows[b].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
          {
            exists = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (!exists)
        {
          mydatagrid.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

        }

      }
    }
  }
```

Also you can probably rewrite the whole thing like this and it'll be much faster (the key being a hash set that keeps track of which items you've already added and more or less instantly tells you if a given string is or isn't already added):

```
  try
  {
    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt); //read excel file  
    HashSet<string> addedItems = new HashSet<string>();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcel;

    mydatagrid.Rows.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      if (!addedItems.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
      {
        mydatagrid.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        addedItems.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I used your code and it took 20 sec to filter 100k values. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TaW - Or do data manipulation through a grid view...20 seconds for 100K values is still crazy slow (although apparently fast enough :).  But I don't know grid views or DataTables well enough to give advice there.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change exists from string to bool
2. Create task for work each task have number of loop less than 5000 (by you work find) see Task.wait https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx
3. Use mydatagrid.Rows.Add after filter twice data complete , first store it on List and use linq find data (where) instead while . see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.1

I think it can help you a little ....